# Why is cross_val_predict so much slower than fit for KNeighborsClassifier?

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Running locally on a Jupyter notebook and using the MNIST dataset (28k entries, 28x28 pixels per image, the following takes **27 seconds**.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=1)
knn_clf.fit(pixels, labels)
```

However, the following takes **1722 seconds**, in other words **~64 times longer**:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(knn_clf, pixels, labels, cv = 3, n_jobs=1)
```

My naive understanding is that `cross_val_predict` with `cv=3` is doing 3-fold cross validation, so I'd expect it to fit the model 3 times, and so take at least ~3 times longer, but I don't see why it would take 64x!

To check if it was something specific to my environment, I ran the same in a [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QsY4vbHfyb7mBcFGHjeUdnVQZetNT3g-) - the difference was less extreme (**15x**), but still way above the ~3x I expected:

What am I missing? Why is cross_val_predict so much slower than just fitting the model?

In case it matters, I'm running scikit-learn 0.20.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`KNN` is also called as lazy algorithm because during fitting it does nothing but saves the input data, specifically there is no learning at all.

During predict is the actual distance calculation happens for each test datapoint. Hence, you could understand that when using `cross_val_predict`, `KNN` has to predict on the validation data points, which makes the computation time higher!

Comment: That's really helpful and makes sense, thanks! I ran a simple predict on the input dataset against the initial model learn and the predict step took as long as the entire cross-validation run, which confirms what you say nicely.

Answer (score 2):

cross_val_predict does a fit and a predict so it might take longer than just fitting, but I did not expect 64 times longer