# cross_val_predict is not completing. No error message

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, knn

I'm trying to implement the use of KNearestNeighbors on the MNIST example dataset.

When trying to use cross_val_predict the script just continues to run no matter how long I leave it for.

Is there something I am missing/doing wrong?

Any feedback is appreciated.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import numpy as np
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1) #Imports the dataset into the notebook

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]

y=y.astype(np.uint8)
X=X.astype(np.uint8)#For machine learning models to understand the output must be casted to an interger not a string.

X.shape, y.shape

y=y.astype(np.uint8) #For machine learning models to understand the output must be casted to an interger not a string.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:] #Separate the data into training and testing sets

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

y_train_knn_pred = cross_val_predict(knn_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3)

f1_score(y_train, y_train_knn_pred, average="macro")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the `n_jobs=-1`**

> The number of CPUs to use to do the computation. None means 1 unless
> in a joblib.parallel_backend context. -1 means using all processors

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import numpy as np
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1) #Imports the dataset into the notebook

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
y=y.astype(np.uint8)
X=X.astype(np.uint8)#For machine learning models to understand the output must be casted to an interger not a string.


y=y.astype(np.uint8) #For machine learning models to understand the output must be casted to an interger not a string.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:] #Separate the data into training and testing sets

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=-1) # HERE
knn_clf.fit(X_train, y_train) # this took seconds on my macbook pro

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

y_train_knn_pred = cross_val_predict(knn_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3, n_jobs=-1) # AND HERE

f1_score(y_train, y_train_knn_pred, average="macro")
```

Comment: Isnt't it sufficient to use n_jobs=-1 in the KNeighborsClassifier only? I have once seen weird problems after using this both for model and score.

Comment: I use `n_jobs=-1` both in `cross_val_predict` and `KNeighborsClassifier`. I have never seen weird problems

Comment: I'm also using a Macbook pro. Cross_val_predict is even when using all processors is taking a long time. What was your run time? (Ball Park Figure)

Comment: the `Cross_val_predict` is also slow for me and usually everyone.  the fast is the `knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=-1)`

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion comes from the point that the KNN algorithm fit call is so much faster than the prediction. From another SO post:

[Why is cross_val_predict so much slower than fit for KNeighborsClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304970/why-is-cross-val-predict-so-much-slower-than-fit-for-kneighborsclassifier/54307798)

> KNN is also called as lazy algorithm because during fitting it does
> nothing but saves the input data, specifically there is no learning at
> all.
>
> During predict is the actual distance calculation happens for each
> test datapoint. Hence, you could understand that when using
> cross_val_predict, KNN has to predict on the validation data points,
> which makes the computation time higher!

Therefore a lot of computation power is needed when you look at the size of your input. data. Using multiple cpus or minimizing dimension could be useful.

If you want to use multiple CPU cores you can pass the argument "`n_jobs`" to `cross_val_predict` and to `KNeighborsClassifier`to set the amount of cores to be used. Set it to `-1` to use all cores available

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, thanks for linking that post.